# Java Timing Library

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I'm looking for something in JodaTime or similar which will let me obtain a Duration from a string passed in.

My string will look like: "00:04:23" (HH:MM:SS) I'd like to be able to get that converted to other time units easily.

Unfortunately [Duration.parse()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Duration.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) from JodaTime doesn't work.  Is there another method which would do this, or do I need to roll my own?

As requested some examples:

- `01:34:22` -> 1 hour 34 minutes and 22 seconds
- `00:04:23` -> 4 minutes and 23 seconds
- `00:00:46` -> 46 seconds

It's easy to roll own, but was curious if there was a built in for that, which I was just missing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and a desired result or output?

Comment: You mean you want human-readable strings, but ones that can be trivially created using a split, parse, and sprintf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still pretty new to JodaTime, but using `PeriodFormatterBuilder` to obtain a `Period` and then converting it to a `Duration` seemed to work for me:

```
String input = "12:14:02";
ReadWritablePeriod period = new MutablePeriod();
new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
        .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
        .appendSeconds().toParser().parseInto(period, input, 0, null);

Duration duration = period.toPeriod().toStandardDuration();
```

I'm not sure what the impact of a null `Locale` is here.